# PyWinAuto drop and drag mouse from control frame co-ords to another

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to populate an in house application list using PyWinAuto. I have 2 different frames. Unfortunately there are very few examples online of this. I have nothing within the frames given by Swapy/print_control_identifiers, thus I'm using co-ords.

Here is what I have worked out so far..

This is ok but how to drop:

```
app.foo.DragMouse(button='left',pressed='',press_coords=(85,65))
```

Problem below, there should be a way to add release_coords to the above but using another frame with the release_coords. So I am trying to use a different frame (bar) to drop but no:

```
app.bar.Drop(button='left',pressed='',coords=(240,26))
```

The below works but only within the same frame and I need to drop and drag from foo to bar frames with coords:

```
app.onlyfoo.DragMouse(button='left',pressed='',press_coords=(85,65),release_coords=(85,200))
```

I've looked at all the relevant docs online and if I see any more notepad example I shall scream.

Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I created a small example with the new pywinauto 0.6. It just tries to drag-n-drop a tree view item on a list box. (Be careful with your currently open folder)

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.Application(backend=u'uia')
appconnect = app.start(u'notepad.exe')
dlg = app.UntitledNotepad
dlg.menu_select(u'File->Open')
dlg.Open.TreeView.get_item("\\Desktop\Libraries").expand()
tv_music = dlg.Open.TreeView.get_item("\\Desktop\Libraries\Music")
# here we drag an item between controls of the dialog
tv_music.drag_mouse_input(dlg.Open.ListBox.wrapper_object())
```

Answer (score 0):

`DragMouseInput()` method has `absolute=False` parameter be default. You can override it with `absolute=True` and use absolute screen coordinates. Yes, it's kind of workaround for now.

The question is very good. We're just reviewing this functionality before new release. Will consider your feedback. Thanks a lot!

Comment: app.TFrmMain.DragMouseInput(button='left',
                            absolute=True,
                            press_coords=(110,300),
                            release_coords=(500,225))

Comment: But of course, abolute co-ords mean you must have your app in the exact same place all the time.. There must be a better way..

Comment: Sure. But absolute coordinates might be converted from relative ones.

Comment: Could you give an example? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `.ClientToScreen(point)` method for `.Rectangle().mid_point()` return value as a method param. Sorry, no time for writing an example right now. Will be offline the rest of this week.

Comment: Hi Vas, Did you ever action this? I have had to create an elaborate maxed windowed application with both normal and absolute coords to satisfy the lack of inter frame working..

Comment: Hi, we reworked this in pywinauto 0.6.0 (thanks @vitswd). See his answer for the reference.

Comment: pywinauto 6.0: drag_mouse_input(dst=(0, 0), src=None, button='left', pressed='', absolute=True) Click on src, drag it and drop on dst
-dst is a destination wrapper object or just coordinates.
-src is a source wrapper object or coordinates. If src is None the self is used as a source object.
-button is a mouse button to hold during the drag. It can be “left”, “right”, “middle” or “x” pressed is a key on the keyboard to press during the drag.
-absolute specifies whether to use absolute coordinates for the mouse pointer locations.
No frame to frame ability..

Comment: Hmm... Do you need to switch focus from src to dst window during drag-n-drop? I.e. making dst window active before drop?

Comment: Popping this conversation up - how can I drag from on application and drop into another? I tried this     `app1.OnSight.ItemsView.drag_mouse_input(dest.rectangle().mid_point(), orig.rectangle().mid_point(), button="left", absolute=True)` but I think that app1 in the beginning is the problem why my folder doesn't get dropped in app2.
@VasilyRyabov any suggestions?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Any update regarding how can I drag a folder from one frame and drop it into another frame? doesn't seem to work yet.

Comment: Amir, could you please create an issue in GitHub or create a new SO question? I'm monitoring SO comments pretty rarely so it's easy to miss them.